# Cdf of $f(x) = 0.075x + 0.2,3 < x < 5$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let $X$ have the following probability density function:
>   $$f(x) =\begin{cases} 0.075x + 0.2,&\text{for }3 < x < 5\\
>         0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

It derives into cdf 
$ 0.0375x^2 + 0.2x - 0.9375$

Can anyone explain to me how to get the $(-0.9375)$ in this answer?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you get when you compute $\int_3^x f(t)\ \mathsf dt$?

Comment: ok it should be 0.075t +0.2dt but im not understanding the notes correctly as the next step states 0.0375x^2 +0.2x -0.9375 the 0.9375 part is confusing me

Comment: Did you compute the integral?

Comment: ok got it! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the possible values of $X$ are $3<x<5$, then to calculate the cdf, we have
$$P(X\leq x) = \int_3^x f_X(t)\,dt = \int_3^x 0.075t + 0.2\,dt.$$

Final answer.

> $$\int_3^x 0.075t + 0.2\,dt = 0.0375 x^2+0.2 x-0.9375.$$